# How do I migrate keychain & provisioning profile between two Macbooks?

Tags: macbook, migration, keychain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrating keychains between Mac machines](https://superuser.com/questions/36733/migrating-keychains-between-mac-machines)

I have a Macbook that already works for my iPhone development, everything is working fine and keychain certificate and provisioning profiles are correctly installed. I got a new Macbook Pro.

How do I migrate settings that I have on the old Macbook to the new one in order to work on both?

The settings I'm reffering to are: Keychain, provisioning profile, etc.

Comment: @Tom - it's not just a superuser question though, it's specific to his developer account with apple.  Maybe splitting hairs, but as someone who wears both hats, this is specific to the developer, not the sysadmin.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Ah, my guesses were wrong. Thought those were settings on the computer, not in an online developer service... :-)

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, this is covered quite completely on developer.apple.com - go to your developer account and search for export keychain.  This will give you all the information necessary to start using your new machine.

In a nutshell, just export your private and public keys and import them to the new Mac.  You can copy the developer.cer and provisioning profiles if you would like, or just get them reissued from apple again (both paths will create the same information)

Comment: I did the downloads but where can i get the .p12 file for certificates because the one i had from my previous laptop gives "invalid or expired certificate"

Comment: when you export them they're invalid? (if so, I recommend asking this specifically on the apple forums, your answers will be more directed that way)